# Ionic 6 Dynamic Data & Sort Function

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, sorting, ionic-framework

I'm having an issue using a function to sort an array:

I'm using a cartService which holds all the product data like this

```html
 public product: Product[] = [
    {
      id:0,
  class: 'large',
  link: '/bars/0/',
  title:'bar zero',
  web1:'',
  },
  {
      id:1,
  class: 'large',
  link: '/hotel/1/',
  title:'hotel one',
  web1:'',
  },
  {
      id:2,
  class: 'large',
  link: '/bar/2/',
  title:'bar two',
  web1:'',
  }
  ];
```

and then to call the products

```html
getProducts(): Product[] {
    return this.product;

  }
```

All works well using this in the page which calls the component providing a list of products using a filter by id pipe

```
<app-bars *ngFor="let product of getProducts() | filterbyid:{loctype: 'bars'}" [product]="product"></app-bars>
```

When you click on the view button

```
<ion-button [routerLink]="'/view-bars/' + product.id"></ion-button>
```

It sends you to the product page.

I'm trying to get the data to sort by title alphabetically. When I try this

```html
getProducts(): Product[] {
    this.product.sort((a,b) => (a.title > b.title) ? 1 : ((b.title > a.title) ? -1 : 0))
    return this.product;

  }
```

all the products display alphabetically but when you press the view button it takes you to a completely different product. The rendered html is showing the link to the product correctly.

Obviously the sort function is causing the issue. Does anyone know anyway of solving this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code:

1. You should NOT be using a method in the ngFor: `*ngFor="let product of getProducts() | filterbyid:{loctype: 'bars'}"`. And you don't need the filterbyid either.

You should be assigning the products to a variable and use that instead of the getProducts.

```
*ngFor="let product of products"
```

3. products array should be sorted before being used. Your getProducts method is not getting anything, it's just sorting.
4. Review the Angular Docs, this is angular basics which the docs cover.